# adding numbers from a counter but also creating new buttons with new counters

Tags: javascript, html, counter

What i want to do is....when the counter button is clicked....increment a span to see how many times its been clicked but also create a new counter with its own incrementor

I have it somewhat working but when i create a new button....the counter doesnt work

anyone help me out with what im missing?

this is also done in vanilla js and html

template:

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" id="increase" onClick="increaseCounter()">click</button>
  <span id="amount"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var counter = 0

function increaseCounter() {

  let button = document.getElementById("increase");
  let span = document.getElementById("amount");

  counter += 1;

  span.innerHTML = counter;

  createNewButton();
}

function createNewButton() {
  let container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
  let btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerHTML = "new button";
  btn.id = "increase";
  container.appendChild(btn);

  let span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHTML = 0;
  span.id = "amount";

  container.appendChild(span);
}
```

LINK: https://codepen.io/zomdar/pen/ZEGPxNP?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few things you should look for:

1- The event listener is only affected to the first button you assign as it is an inline event listener. So new buttons won't have the event listener.

2- If you want to have a new span containing the amount everyone, you must have a different ID for each span (or set the innerHTML directly as I did) or it will be the same span changing.

Note - The ID attribute should be unique in the page, every time you create a button the same ID is attributed. You should use the class attribute (non-unique value) or a different ID every time (e.g. `"amount"+counter`)

```js
function increaseCounter() {

  let button = document.getElementById("increase");
  let span = document.getElementById("amount");

  counter += 1;

//   span.innerHTML = counter;

  createNewButton();
}

function createNewButton() {
  let container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
  let btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerHTML = "new button";
  btn.id = "increase"; // UNIQUE ID !!!
  btn.onclick = increaseCounter;
  container.appendChild(btn);

  let span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHTML = counter;
  span.id = "amount";

  container.appendChild(span);
}
```

Comment: this works....but i want to keep every counter private and add them up....how do i keep adding to the current scoped counter?

Comment: You can do so by passing the counter value to your function : `createNewButton(counter)`. However, your counter is available in the global scope, put `let` to define it in the local scope. It if it is solved, you can mark it as so.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass along the element that was clicked as a parameter of the increaseCounter function and then get the nextElementSibling of that (the span associated with it), grab the innerHTML (current count) of it, then increment it by 1. This will prevent you from having to fetch the elements by id (as mentioned in the answer by clota974, you want your id's to be unique). You were also missing adding the onclick function for the buttons you were creating as well.

References:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_nextelementsibling.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Here's the example code:

```js
function increaseCounter(el) {
  /* increment the span associated with this button (nextElementSibling is the span) */
  el.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = parseInt(el.nextElementSibling.innerHTML) + 1;
  createNewButton();
}

function createNewButton() {
  let container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
  let btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerHTML = "new button";
  btn.onclick = function() {
    increaseCounter(this);
  };
  container.appendChild(btn);

  let span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHTML = 0;

  container.appendChild(span);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" onClick="increaseCounter(this)">click</button>
  <span>0</span>
</div>
```